# Can I improve my chance to find reagents?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I've noticed a lot of different plants in Kingdoms of Amalur can be harvested. However, when I harvest them, nine times out of ten I'm met with the message:

> No reagents found.

**Is there a way to improve my chances of successfully collecting reagents?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every skill point you spend in Alchemy increases your chances of successfully collecting reagents.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there are any ways *other* than adding points to Alchemy? Certain enchantments or potions, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, that in fact increases you chances of collecting reagents. When i was only level 1 alchemy, I got 1 regeant out of 10, I'm now at level 8 and it's like 1/3. It does in fact help a lot.

Comment: There are potions that will temporarily raise Alchemy, and thus help you harvest better, but it all comes back to the Alchemy skill.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was curious about. I also saw in another answer that there are some armor pieces that will give a bonus to certain skills.

Answer (score 0):

The potions you need after mid game all require alchemy as a lot of them are incredibly expensive or very limited.  There are about 4 to 5 trainers total in the world for alchemy so as you go through the game with solid coin you can purchase enough ability to become more successful.  The issue becomes that you will need to harvest more difficult ones and that is when the level makes a huge difference.  Blood roots, prismere dust, etc,... all still fail on occasion and I am maxed out.  It isn't important to have any ability in alchemy until you are about 70% to 80% through.  You can get by with 0 alchemy for the majority of the game.